# Intellij Persistence console - anonymous column names

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using Intellij persistence console (JPA queries) to test queries against MySQL8 DB.

When I use:

```
SELECT b FROM Bird b
```

I get columnn names returned:

[image]

As soon as I select column names with :

```
SELECT b.name FROM Bird b
```

Or

```
SELECT b.name AS name FROM Bird b
```

I dont get column names.

[image]

Is there a setting to fix this?

Comment: Please follow the related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-243514

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in IntelliJ.
You can vote for the corresponding issue on [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-158176).